# How to row filter using dropdown which one multiple option selectable in DataTable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

```
var table = $('#RecognizeForm').dataTable({
            "bServerSide": false,
            guid=@ViewBag.guid',
            "sAjaxSource": "/RecognizeForm/LoadRecognizedData",
            "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
                aoData.push({ "name": "files", "value": files })
                aoData.push({ "name": "guid", "value": '@ViewBag.guid' })
            },
            "ajax": {
                "url": '/RecognizeForm/LoadRecognizedData',
                "type": "POST",
                "data": function (d) {
                    return $.extend({}, d, {
                        "files": files,
                        "guid": '@ViewBag.guid'
                    });
                }
            },
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "paging": true,
            "searching": true,
            "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 50, 75, 100],
            "aoColumns": [
                            { "sName": "FileName", "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": false, "width": 120, "visible": false },
                            { "sName": "MasterFormName", "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": false, "visible": false },
                            { "sName": "PageNumber", "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": false, "width": 95 },
                            { "sName": "FieldName", "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": false, "width": 150 },
                            { "sName": "Type", "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": false, "width": 80 },
                            { "sName": "Result", "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": false },
                            { "sName": "Confidence", "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": false, "width": 80 },
            ],
            //"drawCallback": function (settings) {
            //    var api = this.api();
            //    var rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
            //    var last = null;

            //    api.column(0, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (group, i) {
            //        if (last !== group) {
            //            $(rows).eq(i).before(
            //                '<tr class="group" style=\"background: #CCC;font-weight: bold;\"><td colspan="7">' + group + '</td></tr>'
            //            );
            //            last = group;
            //        }
            //    });
            //},
            initComplete: function () {
                debugger
                this.api().columns().every(function () {
                    var column = this;
                    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                        .on('change', function () {
                            debugger
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );

                            column
                                .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                                .draw();
                        });

                    column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                    });
                });
            },

            processing: false
        });
    });
```

I have used this but multiple select dropdown list is not available in data table.Single selection is working but multiple dropdown is not working .I want 
 to filter on all columns for row and with multiple selection posible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **You can Try This**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Airi Satou</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>2008/11/28</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2012/12/02</td>
            <td>$372,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2012/08/06</td>
            <td>$137,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>2010/10/14</td>
            <td>$327,900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>39</td>
            <td>2009/09/15</td>
            <td>$205,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sonya Frost</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2008/12/13</td>
            <td>$103,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jena Gaines</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2008/12/19</td>
            <td>$90,560</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
            <td>Support Lead</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2013/03/03</td>
            <td>$342,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Charde Marshall</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>2008/10/16</td>
            <td>$470,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2012/12/18</td>
            <td>$313,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>2010/03/17</td>
            <td>$385,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael Silva</td>
            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2012/11/27</td>
            <td>$198,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paul Byrd</td>
            <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2010/06/09</td>
            <td>$725,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gloria Little</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2009/04/10</td>
            <td>$237,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bradley Greer</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2012/10/13</td>
            <td>$132,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Dai Rios</td>
            <td>Personnel Lead</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>2012/09/26</td>
            <td>$217,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
            <td>Development Lead</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2011/09/03</td>
            <td>$345,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Yuri Berry</td>
            <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td>2009/06/25</td>
            <td>$675,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Caesar Vance</td>
            <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2011/12/12</td>
            <td>$106,450</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Doris Wilder</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>Sidney</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2010/09/20</td>
            <td>$85,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
            <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/10/09</td>
            <td>$1,200,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>42</td>
            <td>2010/12/22</td>
            <td>$92,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>2010/11/14</td>
            <td>$357,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>2011/06/07</td>
            <td>$206,850</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fiona Green</td>
            <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>48</td>
            <td>2010/03/11</td>
            <td>$850,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shou Itou</td>
            <td>Regional Marketing</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>2011/08/14</td>
            <td>$163,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michelle House</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Sidney</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2011/06/02</td>
            <td>$95,400</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Suki Burks</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>2009/10/22</td>
            <td>$114,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/05/07</td>
            <td>$145,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
            <td>Team Leader</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2008/10/26</td>
            <td>$235,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Martena Mccray</td>
            <td>Post-Sales support</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/03/09</td>
            <td>$324,050</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Unity Butler</td>
            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/12/09</td>
            <td>$85,675</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/12/16</td>
            <td>$164,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
            <td>Secretary</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2010/02/12</td>
            <td>$109,850</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>62</td>
            <td>2009/02/14</td>
            <td>$452,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2008/12/11</td>
            <td>$136,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>2008/09/26</td>
            <td>$645,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Olivia Liang</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2011/02/03</td>
            <td>$234,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bruno Nash</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>2011/05/03</td>
            <td>$163,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2009/08/19</td>
            <td>$139,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Thor Walton</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2013/08/11</td>
            <td>$98,540</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Finn Camacho</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/07/07</td>
            <td>$87,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
            <td>Data Coordinator</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2012/04/09</td>
            <td>$138,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2010/01/04</td>
            <td>$125,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td>2012/06/01</td>
            <td>$115,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
            <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2013/02/01</td>
            <td>$75,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cara Stevens</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/12/06</td>
            <td>$145,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hermione Butler</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2011/03/21</td>
            <td>$356,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lael Greer</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2009/02/27</td>
            <td>$103,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2010/07/14</td>
            <td>$86,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shad Decker</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/11/13</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael Bruce</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>2011/06/27</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Donna Snider</td>
            <td>Customer Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$112,000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            initComplete: function () {
                this.api().columns().every(function () {
                    var column = this;
                    var select = $('<select multiple><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                        .on('change', function () {
                            debugger
                            //var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(

                            //    $(this).val()
                            //);

                            column
                                .search($(this).val().join('|'), true, false)
                                .draw();
                        });

                    column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: hi i have something similar with `2 cols [Customer] [Order]` in a table. i.e many orders to one customer, since `Order` is a dropdown list, I want to change/select a different `Order` in col, how can I filter and show the Orders in the ddl based on customer in the first col?